# Showing time it takes a particle to reach a point is finite

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, physics

This question comes from a physics text, but I believe my issue is a mathematical one.

> Suppose a particle is moving along the real line starting at $x_0$ subject to the potential $V$ with $V(x)<E_0$ for all $x\in[x_0,x_1)$ and $V(x_1)=E_0$ for some constant $E_0$ (the energy of the particle). Further suppose that $V'(x_1)\ne0$. Show that the particle reaches the point $x_1$ in finite time.

Let $x\in[x_0,x_1)$. Then the time it takes to reach $x$ is given by
$$t(x)=\int_{x_0}^x\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E_0-V(y))}}dy.$$ So the time it takes to reach $x_1$ is
$$t(x_1)=\lim_{x\to x_1}\int_{x_0}^x\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E_0-V(y))}}dy.$$ I need to show that this is finite. How can this be done with the limited knowledge of the potential? One thing I believe should be noted is that $$\frac{dt}{dx}=\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(E_0-V(x))}}$$ in the interval $[x_0,x_1)$, which blows up near $x_1$.

Comment: How do you get $E_0$ in the expression for $t(x)$? Shouldn't it be $V(x_0)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, if $V'(x_1)\neq 0$, then $V'(x_1)>0$.  Rewrite the integral as
$$\tau:=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2\big(V(x_1)-V(x)\big)}}\,\text{d}x=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(x_1-x)}}\,\left(\frac{V(x_1)-V(x)}{x_1-x}\right)^{-\frac12}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
Since $V$ is differentiable at $x_1$, we see that, if $\epsilon:=\dfrac{V'(x_1)}{2}$, then there exists a positive real number $\delta<\dfrac{x_1-x_0}{2}$ such that
$$\left|\frac{V(x_1)-V(x)}{x_1-x}-V'(x_1)\right|<\epsilon\,.$$
Therefore,
$$\dfrac{V'(x_1)}{2}=V'(x_1)-\epsilon<\frac{V(x_1)-V(x)}{x_1-x}<V'(x_1)+\epsilon=\frac{3V'(x_1)}{2}\,.$$
Hence,
$$\begin{align}\int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(x_1-x)}}\,\left(\frac{V(x_1)-V(x)}{x_1-x}\right)^{-\frac12}\,\text{d}x
&\leq \int_{x_1-\delta}^{x_1}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(x_1-x)}}\,\left(\frac{V'(x_1)}{2}\right)^{-\frac12}\,\text{d}x
\\&=2\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{V'(x_1)}}\,\sqrt{\delta}<\infty\,.\end{align}$$
Also, clearly,
$$\int_{x_0}^{x_1-\delta}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{2(x_1-x)}}\,\left(\frac{V(x_1)-V(x)}{x_1-x}\right)^{-\frac12}\,\text{d}x<\infty\,.$$
Thus, $\tau<\infty$.

**P.S.**  The converse (namely, if $\tau<\infty$, then $V'(x_1)\neq 0$) is not true.  For $\tau$ to be finite, it suffices to have $V(x_1)-V(x) =\omega\big(|x-x_1|^2\big)$ for $x$ near $x_1$ (or $V'(x)=\omega\big(|x-x_1|\big)$).  (Here, $\omega$ is the *small omega* notation.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation.)

---

According to the OP, the book claims that $V'(x_1)=0$ implies $\tau=\infty$.  We shall prove that this is false (unless $V$ is assumed to be analytic at $x_1$).

**Counterexample.**  Pick a real number $\lambda$ such that $1<\lambda<2$.  Suppose that $k:=V(x_1)$.  Take
$$V(x):=k\left(1-\left(\frac{x_1-x}{x_1}\right)^\lambda\right)\,.$$
Therefore,
$$V(x_1)-V(x)=k\left(\frac{x_1-x}{x_1}\right)^\lambda\,.$$
That is,
$$\tau=\int_{x_0}^{x_1}\,\sqrt{\frac{m}{k\left(\frac{x_1-x}{x_1}\right)^\lambda}}\,\text{d}x\,.$$
By setting $\xi:=\dfrac{x_1-x}{x_1}$ and $\xi_0:=\dfrac{x_1-x_0}{x_1}$, we get
$$\tau=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\,x_1\,\int_0^{\xi_0}\,\xi^{-\frac{\lambda}{2}}\,\text{d}\xi=\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}\,x_1\,\frac{\xi_0^{1-\frac{\lambda}{2}}}{1-\frac{\lambda}{2}}<\infty\,.$$
However,
$$V'(x)=\frac{\lambda}{x_1}\,k\,\left(\frac{x_1-x}{x}\right)^{\lambda-1}\,,$$
whence $V'(x_1)=0$.

Comment: Nice answer! For the inequality after "Hence" I am getting $2\frac{m}{V'(x_1)}\sqrt{\delta}$ on the right hand side, but this is finite as well. However, the next part of the problem is to show that $V'(x_1)=0$ implies $\tau=\infty$, which is the contrapositive of the statement you claim is false. I don't immediately see how having $V(x_1)-V(x)=\omega\big(|x-x_1|^2)$ for $x$ near $x_1$ implies $\tau$ is finite. My attempt to verify it is giving me an inequality with infinity on the right hand side, which tells me nothing. Perhaps you could clarify if you have the time.

Comment: @zbrads2  I made a small mistake.  Thanks for spotting that.

Comment: @zbrads2  I remember that there was another user posted the same question regarding the case $V'(x_1)=0$.  It was a long time ago, and the thread was probably deleted.  After some long discussion, we believe that it was a mistake by the book.  Either the exercise is wrong, or it is assuming (without saying explicitly) that $V(x)$ is analytic at $x=x_1$.  In that case, if $V'(x_1)=0$, then $$V(x_1)-V(x)=\mathcal{O}\big(|x-x_1|^2\big)\,.$$  Physicists have a tendency to think that every function is analytic.

Comment: @zbrads2  I tried to find the old thread, but couldn't find it.  So, I gave you a counterexample.  See my updated answer.

Comment: I completely agree with your counterexample. Thanks again for your answer.